# MVC Site Error while Hosting

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, web-config, hosting

I have below attached image file while trying to host my web site to internet. It has been developed by ASP.net mvc, and the webconfig.file like this;

{

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"/>
    </security>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <!--alt satırı ekledim-->
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler"/> 
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <!--alt satırı ekledim-->
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

}

what can i do to finish hosting ?

[image: Site error while hosting]

Comment: please read this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524582/system-security-securityexception

Answer (score 0):

I hope this issue occurs trusted level of the application. I am believing your web.configuration is missing trusted level configuration, For that, we can add few line as below code

you have to add the `<trust level="Full"/>` under the `<system.web>` the element in the web.config file. I hope these will help you.

Comment: Thanks for helping, i have changed the lines but have this error: Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.